# How to use a c:set assigned variable

Tags: spring, java-ee-6

In my .jsp file I have the code below.  How can I compare the `environment` variable to a string?  Netbeans isn't liking this... I've tried adding `scope="request"` to the `c:set` with no luck.

```
<c:set var="environment" value="<%=(request.getRequestURL().indexOf("localhost") > 0) ? "dev" : "uat"%>"/>
<% if (environment.equals("live")) { %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any particular reason that you wouldn't do this entirely in scriptlet?  You can still access the variable in JSTL if it was defined in scriptlet

```
<% String environment = (request.getRequestURL().indexOf("localhost") > 0) ? "dev" : "uat"; %>
<% if (environment.equals("live")) { %>
<c:out value="${environment}"/>
```

Have a look here:
http://melandri.net/2009/09/16/scriptlet-and-jstl-variable-sharing/

You could also do it entirely in JSTL to:

```
<c:set var="environment" value="${(fn:indexOf(request.requestURL, 'localhost') gt 0) ? 'dev' : 'uat'}"/>
```